# SharePoint 2010 and Office Web apps language packs

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, installation, office-web-apps, language-pack

We need to install SharePoint Server 2010 and Office web app server in a FARM.

For a fresh installation, when we need to install Language packs? Is it before Office web app installation or after installing office web app?

Is there a different language packs for SharePoint Server 2010 and Office web app server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language packs are same for SharePoint server and office web app 2010. You can download them from here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3411

But you have to install the separate service packs for SharePoint server 2010, owa service packs and service pack for language packs. After that you have to apply cu as well.

Installation order, install SharePoint, install owa, install lps and now install updates(sp and cu). Finally run config wizard.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh685255(v=office.14).aspx